# How to delete ubuntu MATE 18.10 and keep Fedora?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora

I have installed Fedora but it has to little storage and i want to only have fedora left so i can have more storage and because i have been used to fedora. The partition of ubuntu and fedora are the same.

[image: Screenshot of disk]

it says that the fedora-root filesystem has 0B left

Comment: 1. I do not see your ubuntu partition. 2. Fedora is using lvm and it appears you have additional space in the lvm. 3. See https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/ch-lvm.html as gparted does not do lvm

Comment: @Panther It is the big one and for some reason the fedora and ubuntu is the same partiotion.

Comment: Fedora and ubuntu can not be the same partition

Answer (score 3):

The partition `fedora` is managed by `lvm`. It basically allows you to take a physical partition and assign parts of it to logical `lvm` partitions as needed, making space allocation more flexible. To learn more, you can read the [arch linux wiki entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LVM#LVM_Building_Blocks), for example.

The tool you are using, `gparted` is not displaying the `lvm` volumes.

You can do so by running `lvdisplay` (list logical volumes) and `pvdisplay` (list physical volumes). The lvm management tools are documented for example in the [redhat docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/LV.html).

Or you can use a graphical tool that properly supports `lvm` (for example: `KDE partition manager`)